# How to bring the proct element before graphelem element

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

**I want to check if graphelem is present before proct element inside parent procstep, I want to place proct element before graphelem. I tried but could not get it right.

Need help to resolve this issue.**

**Sample input**

````
<procstep id="NODE231">
<graphelem id="NODE234">
<graphic graphicname="T2058477" id="NODE235" res_width="3.07in" scale="60"/></graphelem>
<proct>Install the CMP sensor. For engines without PTO: Install the
hatch cover.<br/>For engines equipped with PTO: Install the PTO.</proct>
<note>test note</note>
<caution>test caution</caution>
</procstep>   ```


***expected output***

``` <procstep id="NODE231">
<proct>Install the CMP sensor. For engines without PTO: Install the
hatch cover.<br/>For engines equipped with PTO: Install the PTO.</proct>
<graphelem id="NODE234">
<graphic graphicname="T2058477" id="NODE235" res_width="3.07in" scale="60"/></graphelem>
<note>test note</note>
<caution>test caution</caution>
</procstep> ```

***Sample xsl file I have extracted part of the xsl file to make it look relevant for the question***

```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"   
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>    
    
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="proct">     
 <xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::graphelem">               
 <cmd>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>            
 </cmd>                
   <xsl:apply-templates select="graphelem"/>                 
 </xsl:if>   
 </xsl:template>
 
</xsl:stylesheet>
````

Comment: Is your question not answered?

Comment: Yes I got my answer

Comment: <xsl:copy-of select="* except proct"/> - This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="procstep">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="proct"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*[not(self::proct)]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This has a condition as well, when graphelem is before proct then this is fine but when graphelem is after proct, we do not need to do anything and there will be other elements too.

Comment: I guess you could change `<xsl:copy-of select="graphelem"/>` to `<xsl:copy-of select="* except proct"/>` (requires XSLT 2.0).

Comment: I have modified the input xml and expected out slightly.